# Solving Homogenous Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm having a problem solving for a general solution for this differential equation:
Consider $U(x,y)$ governed by a system of PDEs:

$$ U_{xx}= 0, U_{yy} = 0 $$

How do I solve for its general solution?
Here's what I've tried:
I integrate $U_{xx}$ twice to get $U(x,y)= xf(y)+g(y)$ and I differentiate this by y to get $U_y=xf'(y)+g'(y)$ and I'm stuck.

Am I on the right track? Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You got 
$$
U_y=xf'(y)+g'(y) \quad \implies \quad U_{yy}=xf''(y)+g''(y) = 0
$$
It implies that $f''(y) = g''(y)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! But may I know why does this imply that $f''(y)=g''(y)=0$? Shouldn't this imply that $xf''(y)=-g''(y)$ instead? Thank you!

Comment: @user672518 $f, g$ are functions of $y$ only, so there is no possible way $g''(y)$ can equal $x f''(y)$, unless $f'', g'' = 0$.